# Chrome extension fetching website id data in window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-extension

On click inside the extension

[image]

Fetch id"dfa5" text data and alert

I am looking for when someone clicks inside the extension button, then fetch h1 id"" data. and alert

[image]

```
manifest.json

{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Sample Name",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "This is a sample description",
    "short_name": "Short Sample Name",
    "permissions": ["activeTab","tabs", "declarativeContent", "storage", "<all_urls>"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["background.css"],
        "js": ["background.js"]
      }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Does a thing when you do a thing",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icons/icon16.png",
        "32": "icons/icon32.png"
      }
    }
   }
```

```
background.js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    var button = document.getElementById("asdfjk")
    button.addEventListener("click", () => {
        sdef();
    })
})

function sdef() {
    var ksdfh = document.getElementById("dfa5").innerHTML; // current website page h1 id="dfa5"
    alert(ksdfh)
}
```

Comment: So what is problem? The `ksdfh` variable should contain html content of `#dfa5`

Comment: it is not facing data

Comment: The code work corrently in [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgd4b5z3/). To finding problem check console.

Comment: console was clear. but inside the alert box, I see "null" value in the alert box

Comment: Maybe selector is incorrect or target element hasn't any text content.

Comment: problem resolved addEventListener create problem thanks for your effort